# query all records with maximum id in different group from a table in rails environment

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a table `orders` with  `id` and `color` columns, id is unique column.

```
|  id  | color |  
| ---- | ----- |  
|   1  | Red   |  
|   2  | Red   |  
|   3  | Green |  
|   4  | Green |  
|   5  | Blue  |  
|   6  | Blue  |
```

I hope to get all rows with maximum `id` in their `color` group, the query result should be

```
|   2  | Red   |  
|   4  | Green |  
|   6  | Blue  |
```

How can I query the correct result in rails environment with Sqlite3 (dev env) and PostgreSQL 9.3 (production env)

Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect use-case for `DISTINCT ON`: `Order.select('DISTINCT ON  (color) *').order('color, id DESC')`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, thank you for your answer. It seems I don't get correct result. I should get same count with your query+.size and `Order.group(:color).length`, right?

Comment: @CloudBSD `Order.group(:color).count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could write:

```
Order.group(:color).maximum(:id)
```

Comment: Better than my answer as it's a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
Order.select('color, MAX(id) as maxid').group(:color)
```

Optionally, you can add `.order(:color)` before the .group clause.  Should work with either database.